# How to gently defer execution of a function that might return an error?

Tags: go

Most cleanup functions, especially those related to the IO operations, return an `error`, and normally we'd prefer to `defer` their execution in case if we'd not forget to call them when we're done with acquired resources. For example, at some point in the code we might write something like this:

```
var r *SomeResource
var err error
if r, err = Open(/* parameters */); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer r.Close() // This might return an error
```

It seems that if `Close` function returns an error, it'll be ignored. How can we gently process the returned `error` from such a function?

Comment: That's a little too opinionated a question; you're returned an error, handle it however you want! Generally this type of error is something that you want to know about, but not something that you want to break the code flow, so you'd increment a metric or write a log line. Like Seaskyways' answer says, you can write this logic in a closure, or wrap it up into a helper function.

Comment: IMO I think it should fail spectacularly in the function instead of returning error to the main routine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `defer` with a `func() {}()` like so.

```
var r *SomeResource
var err error
if r, err = Open(/* parameters */); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer func() {
    if err = r.Close(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("ERROR: %v", err)
    }
}()
```

Comment: Alirus, note that nothing forces you to use an anonymous function as suggested here: it's perfectly fine to have a utility function and arrange for it to be executed in a deferred call — [an example](https://play.golang.org/p/VKg3a-4xFaJ). OTOH, an anonymous function usually makes it easy to access the encosing function's return variables, if needed. Still, using this feature is of dubious utility as it may hamper understanding of the control flow; see the answer provided by @PeterSO.

Answer (score 3):

Fail gracefully with an error. Report the first error. Don't overwrite earlier errors. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func demo() (name string, err error) {
    filename := `test.file`
    f, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    defer func() {
        e := f.Close()
        if e != nil {
            if err == nil {
                err = e
            }
        }
    }()

    // do someting with the file
    name = f.Name()
    fi, err := f.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        return name, err
    }
    if fi.Size() == 0 {
        err = fmt.Errorf("%s: empty file", filename)
        return name, err
    }

    return name, err
}

func main() {
    name, err := demo()
    fmt.Println(name, err)
}
```

Comment: `if e != nil {` this check inside defer is probably redundant

Comment: In addition to what @zerkms noted, which is supposedly right, AFAIK with _named_ return parameters, specifying `return` arguments explicitly, is also redundant. So, one can simply write `return` instead of `return name, err` in this example.

Comment: @Alirus: Just because you can do something doesn't make it good practice. From the codereview guidelines: "be explicit with your return values. " Readability is paramount.

Comment: @peterSO it probably a language issue (I'm presumably a native speaker). My point is that if that check is removed - nothing would change.

Comment: err, I'm presumably **NOT** a native speaker

Comment: @zerkms, the check implements the «Don't overwrite earlier errors» bit from the Peter's answer. That is, if `Close()` returns an error but the function already generated an error, we do not stomp over that original error — which, supposedly, is a more important one. Of course, the behaviour should be judged on a case-by-case basis—for instance, a failure to `Close()` a file opened for writing might indeed represent a grave error. Hence one might take several routes at solving it: 1) log the error hinting at where it happened and the fact it wasn't handled; …

Comment: @zerkms, …2) create a value of a custom type accumulating several errors into one, and return it; 3) panic — indicating a "double fault" condition. This freedom is one of the strong sides of the Go's approach to error handling, which is often overlooked by newcomers (and "professional blog posters") ;-)

Comment: @kostix you would not overwrite the original error if you simply remove the `if e != nil {` and the corresponding closing brace https://pastebin.com/FzVL4JT7 - this code is identical isn't it. My point is that - that very condition does not check anything useful

Comment: @zerkms, yes you're correct. This "reads backwards" a bit but is nonetheless valid, I stand corrected.

Answer (score -1):

We can handle this in ways like:

**way-1:**

```
func myFn() error {
    var err error
    if r, err = Open(/* parameters */); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer func() {
        if cErr = r.Close(); cErr != nil {
            err = cErr
        }
    }()
    return err
}
```

**way-2:**

```
func myFn() error {
    var err error
    if r, err = Open(/* parameters */); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer func() {
        if cErr = r.Close(); cErr != nil {
            // we can log the error
            // or
            // whatever we want to do
        }
    }()
    return err
}
```

I have also find a nice blog on this topic, i mean handling error when defer func returns an error. Check here https://blog.learngoprogramming.com/5-gotchas-of-defer-in-go-golang-part-iii-36a1ab3d6ef1.